# Добавление кнопки с ссылкой

Tags: c#, html, веб-программирование, button, blazor

Коллеги, доброго времени суток.
У меня меня есть страница формата ".razor" и я пытаюсь сделать кнопку с url по которой пользователь будет переходить по ссылке.

На бэке я генерирую в строку ссылку:

```
private string BuildAuthorizationUrl()
{
    var url = new StringBuilder(_vkModel.Url)
        .Append(_vkModel.ClientId)
        .Append("&")
        .Append(_vkModel.Display)
        .Append("&")
        .Append(_vkModel.RedirectUri)
        .ToString();

    return url;
}
```

Ссылка получается корректной и работает если вставить ее в браузер:

```
https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=000000&display=page&redirect_uri=https://localhost:44346
```

Через контролер передаю ее на .razor страницу. Роуты и ActionResult специально не юзаю, т.к. хочу накидать рабочий скелет и затем нарастить. Дебажил, ссылка передается также корректно

```
public string AuthorizationIndex()
{
    var vkUrl = controller.GetAuthorizationsUrl();

    return vkUrl;
}
```

В razor странице добавляю кнопку:

```
@page "/fetchdata"

@using Project.Controllers

@{Controller controller = new Controller(); }

<form action=@controller.AuthorizationIndex()>
    <button>Click Me</button>
</form>

<button formaction=@controller.AuthorizationIndex()> Зарегистрироваться </button>
```

Кнопка "Click me" работает, но ссылка почему-то кладется не корректно после символа "&" добавляется "amp;" и насколько мне известно, использовать такую кнопку не лучший вариант

Вторая кнопка и все остальные, которые я пытался добавить содержат корректную ссылку но не работают.

Как мне правильно создать эту кнопку и передать корректно ссылку? Если вдруг все у меня ужасно и у Вас будет время подсказать больше, буду очень Вам благодарен.

Дополнительный вопрос(если он выходят за рамки данной темы, прошу проигнорить):
1) мне вернется токен, как мне его принять после нажатия на кнопку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помогло это

```
<a href="@controller.AuthorizationIndex() ">
        <span class='btn btn-primary'>Click</span>
</a>
```